# PHP: How to load images onscroll with server-side pagination

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, pagination

I am getting over 1000 images from my another website and I want to request them at the server side when the user scrolls down step-by-step. My problem is they are loading all together and I don't know how to load them partically during the scroll. Lazyload solves only client-side of my problem.

**CODE:**

```
$url = 'http://mydomain/page/';
$string = '';
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    $string .= FetchPage($url.$i);
  }
$image_regex_src_url = '/<img[^>]*'.
'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';

preg_match_all($image_regex_src_url, $string, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$images_url_array = $out[1];

foreach ($images_url_array as $image) {
    $elements = explode('/', $image);
    $name = end($elements);
    $checkname = explode('.', $name);
    if(end($checkname) === 'jpg' || end($checkname) === 'png'){
        $img = 'images/'.$name;
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image);
        if($height < 4000 && $height > 300) {
            if(!file_exists($img)){
                file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($image));
            }
            print_r('<img src="'.$img.'" width="900" />');
        }
    }
}
```

**@EDIT:**

I solved my problem with crawling all data to my server and then outputting it with lazyload.js at client-side.

Comment: img.onload=loadNextImage;

Comment: You can't manage server-side through a client-side. When the user make scroll, this is a client event, not a server feature. So PHP doesn't make anything here. You must use javascript.

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be to output the image source in a data tag (`data-img-src` for example), letting each `src` be empty and then replace it (using js) with the data-tag once the `img` is in view. A good thing would also be to output the `img` width and height inline. This is how most (if not all??) lazyload plugins do it, and I think is one of the best solutions with performance in mind, since you don't need to run a bunch of js to first disable the image loading.

I would personally find a plugin for this and modify the php to match the plugins specifications.